Who first translated Juan Rulfo's Pedro Páramo into English?
In 2011, user hippietrail asked in the previous incarnation of Literature Stack Exchange,

The current English version of Pedro Páramo by Juan Rulfo was translated by Margaret Sayers Peden. I know there was a previous English translation but my Internet search skills are failing me and I can't find the translator's name. Was it by a famous literary translator or by somebody obscure?


The most recent translation of Pedro Páramo is Douglas J. Weatherford's, published by Serpent's Tail in 2024. Weatherford mentions two earlier English translations:

one by Lysander Kemp, published by Grove Press in 1959 and reprinted in 1990;
one by Margaret Sayers Peden, published by Grove Press in 1994 with a foreword by Susan Sontag; reprinted by the University of Texas Press in 2002.

I don't know whether Lysander Kemp was a "famous literary translator". He also translated The Broken Spears: The Aztec Account of the Conquest of Mexico in 1962, Selected Poems of Rubén Darío in 1965 and Carlos Fuentes's novel Aura, also in 1965
